# If $2x-py-3=0$ and $6x+3y+2=0$ are perpendicular what is $p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

If $2x-py-3=0$ and $6x+3y+2=0$ are perpendicular what is $p$?

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. Can you tell in your question what you already know and have tried? This way, it will be more likely that people are willing to help you and give you an answer.

Comment: I tried multiplying the first equation by -1 the add the 2 equation together but get stucked

Answer (score 2):

First method: rewrite the two equations as $y = \frac{2x}{p} - \frac{3}{p}$ (so $p\neq 0)$ and $y = -2x -\frac{2}{3}$. The lines are perpendicular if the products of the two coefficients for $x$ are $-1$: $\frac{2}{p} \cdot -2 = -1$.

If you are familiar with the inproduct and the direction vectors, there is a second method: take this inproduct of $(2,-p)$ and $(6,3)$. This should be equal to zero: $2\cdot 6 - p\cdot 3 = 0$.

Comment: I think you mean $ 2 \times 6 - p\times 3 = 0$ in the second method, by taking $(2, -p)$

Comment: Indeed, thank you for mentioning! I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Slope of the first line $=\dfrac{2}{p}$
Slope of the second line$=-2$

To be perpendicular, $$ \dfrac{2}{p}*(-2)=-1$$
Hence,$$p=4$$